# What does "warning: control reaches end of non-void function"?

Tags: vector, compiler-warnings

I have been getting this warning in my recursion program.
What should I do to remove this warning?

```
vector<int> Min_Max(vector<int>& a,int n,int N,vector<int>& b)
{
    if(n==N-1)
    {
        return b;
    }
    if(a[n]<b[0])
    {
        b[0]=a[n];
    }
    if(a[n]>b[1])
    {
        b[1]=a[n];
    }
    Min_Max(a,n+1,N,b);

}
```

Comment: your function's return type is `vector<int>` so it should return a `vector<int>` on all possible paths before it ends. if it is not going to return anything its return type should be `void`.

Comment: It means that there is an execution path without the return statement. Function returns value and it is an undefined behavior

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

"warning: control reaches end of non-void function" is a warning message that is issued by some compilers when a function with a non-void return type does not have a return statement at the end of its body